# Using ListView of CheckedTextViews with a filter

Tags: android, listview, checkedtextview

I am trying to write a ListView that is filled with CheckedTextViews
and uses a filter to allow the user to quickly search the ListView
(which is backed by an array with a custom ArrayAdapter).  I have set
the multipleChoice flag in the XML that declares the listview and I
can check/uncheck multiple entries when not using the filter.  When
using the filter to search for an entry, I am able to select an entry.
 However, when I clear the filter (by hitting backspace) the entry at
the same position remains checked enventhough it is no longer the
actual entry that I want checked.

I have tried manually setting the checked state on the CheckedTextView
in the adapter's getView() method but that does not seem to be
working.  Just for grins, I tried setting isChecked to false in
*every* CheckedTextView in the ListView, but the CheckedTextView that
was checked while using the filter remains checked.

Has anyone had any luck implementing something like this or have any
recommendations?

Thanks
Adam

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I was looking at [ListView.clearChoices()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#clearChoices%28%29) , but I was hoping there was another way.  What I eneded up doing was calling [ListView.clearChoices()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#clearChoices%28%29) whenever the filter is changed, manually keeping track of what has been selected, and calling [ListView.setItemChecked()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#setItemChecked%28int,%20boolean%29) from [ArrayAdapter.getView()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#getView%28int,%20android.view.View,%20android.view.ViewGroup%29).  This prevents me from having to iterate over the whole list all the time.

Answer (score 4):

You might want to look at [ListView#clearChoices()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#clearChoices%28%29).  The ListView itself is maintaining the choices based on position of the adapter item, not the id of the item.  So if the position changes (e.g., by filtering), the choice positions are essentially no longer valid.

It does also maintain a list of checked ids, which you can retrieve with [ListView#getCheckedItemIds()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AbsListView.html#getCheckedItemIds%28%29), and as long as your adapter has stable ids (i.e., a particular id **always** refers to the same conceptual item, and does **not** vary with the order or filtering of the items), you can use that to restore the checked positions when the filtering changes (you'll have to iterate the entire adapter in order to match up ids to positions).